# How to bind parameter to URL

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, url

This is my jsp code. I want to bind the **catid** parameter to url when I call `getproductsub()` and send ajax request.

```
r.open("GET", "url?catid=" + catid,true);
```

above line seems an error of my code.How can I fix it.

```
<select class="form-control" id="pcategory" name="pcategory" onchange="getproductsub();">

<script>
  function getproductsub() {
    var catid = document.getElementById('pcategory').value;
    var url = window.location.href;
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (r.readyState === 4 && r.status === 200) {}
    };
    r.open("GET", "url?catid=" + catid, true);
    r.send();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Pay attention to ```r.onreadystatechange``` assignation. must be ```r.onreadystatechange = function() {...}``` but you have ```r.onreadystatechange() = function() {...}```

Comment: oh my mistake.I fixed it.thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `window.location.href` gives the complete location including the parameters in the url at the current time. So `?` might be included in it.

You can either use

```
var url = window.document.location.pathname;
```

And concat the `url` to the String passed to `open()`.

```
r.open("GET", url + "?catid=" + catid, true);
```

---

**OR**

Use `getRequestURL()` as you are coding in jsp.

```
r.open("GET", "<%= request.getRequestURL()%>?catid=" + catid, true);
```

Comment: Thanx for your explanation.In the respone  I had to use this.    
 window.location.href ="<%= request.getRequestURL()%>?catid=" + catid;